# Calculating totals to display in table from array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to calcualte a total score for a bowling game here is the code for my class

I cant figure out what is wrong, its something with the loop I think, basically its supposed to track score for every player and keep a running total
[output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4qd.png)

> /*  * Click
> nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt
> to change this license  * Click
> nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit
> this template  */

```
package cis.entity;

import cis.util.CisUtility;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author mm
 */
public class Game {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ENDS = 10;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS = 4;
    private static final String[] player = new String[NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS];
    private static final int[][] scores = new int[NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS][NUMBER_OF_ENDS];
    int[] totals = new int[NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS];

    public void addPlayer() {

        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
            player[counter] = CisUtility.getInputString("Enter name of player #" + (counter + 1));

        }
    }

    public void addScores() {

        for (int endIndex = 0; endIndex < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; endIndex++) {
            for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < player.length; playerIndex++) {
                scores[playerIndex][endIndex] = CisUtility.getInputInt("Enter score number " + (endIndex + 1) + " score for " + player[playerIndex] + "---->");
                showScores();
            }
        }

    }

    public void showScores() {

        System.out.println("Player \tEnd #1 \tEnd #2 \tEnd #3 \tEnd #4 \tEnd #5\tEnd #6 \tEnd #7 \tEnd #8 \tEnd #9 \tEnd #10 \tTotals");

        for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS; playerIndex++) {
            System.out.print(player[playerIndex] + "\t");
            for (int endIndex = 0; endIndex < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; endIndex++) {
                System.out.print(scores[playerIndex][endIndex] + "\t" + totals[0]);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public void calculateTotal() {
        for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS; playerIndex++) {
            for (int endIndex = 0; endIndex < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; endIndex++) {
                totals[0] += scores[playerIndex][endIndex];

            }

        }
    }
}
```